# Setting Env Vars in tcsh

Tags: linux, environment-variables, command-line-interface

Please tell me why I can't set my env var by modifying `~/.profile`?

```
[104] whoami
user

[105]% cat .profile
. /app/share/Profile
# add any personal customizations after this line
set JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_17"

[106]% ~/.profile
user out

[107]% echo $JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME: Undefined variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify ~/.cshrc.

```
[me$]% cat ~/.cshrc
setenv MAVEN_HOME /home/bin/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin
```